# R Shiny Datatable color cell based on value range

Tags: r, shiny, color-scheme, dt

I have this dataset:

`test <- data.frame("type" = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), "goal" = c(3000,4500,250,2000),"Jan" = c(4000,2000,240,800), "Feb" = c(2000,3000,300,1500), "Mar" = c(2800,4000,100,1400) )`

I would like to have a data table display this in my shiny app with color coded cell using the following criteria:

Green: Below 60% of goal
Amber: 60-80% of goal
Red: Above 80% of goal

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvXIG.png)

I have played around with JSCallback option in renderDatatable function but it seems that it needs the cell to be in percentage instead of actual numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please show some ideas/examples which you have tried. We can work on these ideas to help you out.

Comment: There are plenty of examples how to do that on DT page https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html

Answer (score 2):

This is the one I could come up with using `styleInterval` but not sure how scalable you need.

- We first logical values based on Goal vs Actual intervals
- Use that to color the cell

```
#courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50950368/5086335

library(DT)

test <- data.frame("type" = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), "goal" = c(3000,4500,250,2000),"Jan" = c(4000,2000,240,800), "Feb" = c(2000,3000,300,1500), "Mar" = c(2800,4000,100,1400) )

# Green: Below 60% of goal Amber: 60-80% of goal Red: Above 80% of goal


test$jan_goal <- ifelse(test$Jan > test$goal * 0.8, 2,
                        ifelse(test$Jan < test$goal * 0.6, 0,
                               1))

test$feb_goal <- ifelse(test$Feb > test$goal * 0.8, 2,
                        ifelse(test$Feb < test$goal * 0.6, 0,
                               1))

test$mar_goal <- ifelse(test$Mar > test$goal * 0.8, 2,
                        ifelse(test$Mar < test$goal * 0.6, 0,
                               1))


      DT::datatable(
        test,
        rownames = FALSE,
        options = list(
          columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(5,6,7), visible = FALSE))
        )
      ) %>% 
        formatStyle(columns = "Jan",
                    valueColumns = "jan_goal",
                    backgroundColor = styleEqual(levels = c(0,1,2), values = c("#008000","#FFA500","#F00"))) %>% 
        formatStyle(columns = "Feb",
                    valueColumns = "feb_goal",
                    backgroundColor = styleEqual(levels = c(0,1,2), values = c("#008000","#FFA500","#F00"))) %>% 

        formatStyle(columns = "Mar",
                    valueColumns = "mar_goal",
                    backgroundColor = styleEqual(levels = c(0,1,2), values = c("#008000","#FFA500","#F00")))
```

[image]

Comment: Writing this to more vars and then hide them may be a bit cumbersome. You could use `styleInterval` instead of `styleEqual` ([see lukeA's answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323885/how-to-color-specific-cells-in-a-data-frame-table-in-r).