# R DT conditional formatting using non visible column

Tags: r, shiny, dt

This question relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936714/conditional-formatting-in-dt-data-table-r-shiny) but the value that I want to condition on is not the value of the cell but an external column which is available but not shown in the DT.

My example is simple:

```
DT::datatable(
  iris[,1:4],
  editable = TRUE,
  filter = c("bottom"),
  rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = 'Buttons',
  options = list(
    pageLength=21, scrollY='400px',
    dom = 'Brt'
))%>% formatStyle('Sepal.Length', fontWeight = styleInterval(5, c('normal', 'bold')))
```

How would I color-code or apply formatting to a column `Sepal.Length` depending on the value of `iris$Species`

- If `Species` is `setosa` then blue and
- If `Species` is `versicolor` then red  and
- If `Species` is `virginica` then green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job

```
library(DT)
DT::datatable(
  iris,
  editable = TRUE,
  filter = c("bottom"),
  rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = 'Buttons',
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(list(targets = 4, visible = F)),
    pageLength= 150, scrollY='400px',
    dom = 'Brt'
  )) %>% formatStyle(
    'Sepal.Length', 'Species',
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("setosa", "versicolor","virginica"), c('steelblue', 'red', "green"))
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

- use the full dataset;
- hide the desired column with the option `columnDefs`;
- use some Javascript in the option `initComplete` to set the colors.

---

```
jscode <- "function(settings) {
var table = settings.oInstance.api();
var nrows = table.rows().count();
for(var i=0; i<nrows; i++){
var cell0 = table.cell(i,0);
var cell4 = table.cell(i,4);
var species = cell4.data();
var bgcolor;
if(species == 'setosa'){
bgcolor = 'blue';
}else if(species == 'versicolor'){
bgcolor = 'red';
}else{
bgcolor = 'green'
}
cell0.node().style.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
}
}"

DT::datatable(
  iris,
  editable = TRUE,
  filter = c("bottom"),
  rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = 'Buttons',
  options = list(
    pageLength=21, scrollY='400px',
    dom = 'Brtp',
    columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=4)),
    initComplete = JS(jscode)
  ))%>% formatStyle('Sepal.Length', 
                    fontWeight = styleInterval(5, c('normal', 'bold')))
```

[image]